# breaking down how to sort numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm going over [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/arraysort.shtml) sorting tutorial and I'm  having problems understanding it.
I see that the rules are the following when passing in a sortfunction to `.sort()`.

> - Less than 0: Sort "a" to be a lower index than "b"
> - Zero: "a" and "b" should be considered equal, and no sorting    performed.
> - Greater than 0: Sort "b" to be a lower index than "a".

and I'm testing this snippet:

```
var myarray=[25, 8, 7, 41];
console.log(myarray);
console.log(myarray.sort(function(a,b) {
    console.log("a : " , a , " b : " , b, " oper : " , b-a, " arr ");
    return b -a
}));
```

the main part is `return b -a` and this should return the array in descending order I  think because if `b` is larger than `a` it will be placed in a lower index. I think I'm having a hard time under standing what exactly "lower" means. does it mean that it b goes directly before `a` or does `b` go to the beginning of the array?

here is where I'm getting confused. The result of the code is:

```
[25, 8, 7, 41]
a : 25  b : 8  oper : -17  arr
a : 8  b : 7  oper : -1  arr 
a : 7  b : 41  oper : 34  arr 
a : 25  b : 41  oper : 16  arr 
[41, 25, 8, 7]
```

here is just my thinking

since the first 2 comparisons produce a negative `a` goes before `b` so at the end of the first 2 comparisons the array should be something like `[25,8,7,41]` (no change).

Then the next comparison is a positive number(34) so  so I think `b` goes before `a` so it will be now `[25,8,41,7]` then I don't why it compares 25 and 41 next How is `a` = 25 and `b` = 41? can you also show me how to view the array as it is being transformed I tried to do that without success. Thanks in advance.

If you see another question that explains this sorting breakdown in detail I'll be happy to close this question. I don't mean to ask useless questions on SO. most tuts just explain how to sort in general but not break it down. Thank you

Comment: So if I understand right, you want explanation of how sorting works. Right?

Comment: I think your issue is that you are assuming it is using some sort of bubble sort -- it is not.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The details of how `.sort()` does all it's comparisons is implementation specific and not part of any specification.  The point is merely that it uses some algorithm to compare elements in the array and uses your callback function in order to get the result of comparing two elements.

Comment: yea but specifically to where I'm getting confused as mentiond in my questions. the confusion area are placed before question marks.

Comment: If `a` is "lower"  than `b` per your comparison function, that just means `a` should be before `b` in the sorted array.  That's all it means.

Comment: Reverse engineering the sorting algorithm based on which comparisons are used and when would be tedious and horribly boring without teaching you much. Why not learn about the different algorithms instead?

Comment: can you tell me why we are comparing 25 and 41 last. I guess I got confused because because all the other  comparisons looks like they are going in order but those numbers were not in order. I guess they were pushed to the lower indexes. Maybe I'm having a hard time visualizing it.

Comment: @jackblank - As many have said, there is no reason to try to reverse engineer the sort algorithm.  Every browser may implement it differently.  If you want to learn about sort algorithms, pick up a reference on the topic as there are many classic sorting algorithms each with particular strengths.  The answer to why it compares two particular elements is because the sort algorithm does not yet know which of those two is greater and it needs to know - so it calls your callback to find out.

Comment: have you tried this: asc `return a > b` and desc `return a < b`

Comment: @DanielAlmeida - That doesn't handle `a == b` properly.  `return b - a` or `return a - b` are the usual way to achieve a numeric sort in ascending or descending order.

Comment: @jackblank you can refer [MDN - polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)

Comment: You might find this useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

> So is there a way to show the sort process? like when you do a for
>   loop you can console.log the activity your looping. can you
>   console.log the steps that it takes to sort the array? I guess not.

An approach using [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) , [`Math.max()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) ; [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
// `arr` : input array
function _sort(arr) { 
  // declare `min` variable
  // `res` : array that will be returned
  var min = null, res = []; console.log("step 1", min, res);
  // while `arr` contains elements
  while (arr.length) {
    // set `min` to smallest number in `arr`
    min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr); console.log("step 2", min);
    // push `min` to `res` array
    res.push(min); console.log(res);
    // remove `min` element from `arr` array
    arr.splice(arr.indexOf(min), 1); console.log("step 3", arr);
  }
  // return `res` array 
  return res
}

console.log("step 4", _sort([27, 1, 3, 14]))
```

Comment: so it's safe to assume that you are showing me a way to recreate a sorting function. but just to confirm this is not what JS does for `.sort()` right? Thanks for showing me this method.

Comment: @jackblank Yes. See http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.sort , http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/14-Sorting-Were-Doing-It-Wrong.html